# Get Value from Azure App Configuration Store where the content-type is set to application/json in C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to fetch the values from the Azure App configuration store.
I have created a key - `Credentials` with the value

```
{
      "Name": "MyNewCsv",
      "Extension": "csv",
      "Delimeter": "|"
}
```

and I have set its content-type to `application/json`.

I am trying to read this key-value from C# code as below :

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Helper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

public FileConfiguration GetFileConfiguration(string azureKeyName)
        {
            string message = _configuration[azureKeyName];
            var fileConfiguration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileConfiguration>(message);
            return fileConfiguration;
        }
```

I am passing the `azureKeyName` as `Credentials` but when I am debugging the code `message` is null even though the key is created on Azure.
When I am removing the content-type as `application/json` from the App configuration store, Then this code works fine.

Why I am facing trouble when setting the content-type ?
Please help me how can I read the key-value when the content-type is set to `application/json`?

Please help.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: How do you declare a key-value on Azure? Something like Credentials:Name MyNewCsv? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @ElConrado I have edited the question and added the image for you describing how I added the key on azure app configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Credentials` is saved as a JSON object in App Config. Hence, reading it as a `string` is incorrect. You will have to create a class like below:

```
public class Credentials{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Extension{get;set;}
   public string Delimeter{get;set;}
}
```

And then, read it like below:

```
Credentials message = _configuration.GetSection(azureKeyName).Value;
```

Comment: Although, I would like to modify a little .. `Credentials message = _configuration.GetSection(azureKeyName).Value;` solved my problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For me rather this would work:

```
Credentials message = _configuration.GetSection(azureKeyName).Get<Credentials>();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).